# Using .net core and mongodb, is there a way to update only the fields I'm passing in a json?

Tags: c#, mongodb

i'm developing an API using .net core and mongdoDb. I'm trying to create an "edit" method and want my code to update only the fields presents in my json. 
The problem is: 
I have a complex json (nested objects) and only can update the properties presents in root. Every nested object is rewriten by my code when I update any property inside them.

I'm trying to fill a list of UpdateDefinition using Reflection through the objects, and then use the UploadOne method from mongodb driver.

This is my working code. I think i need to make it recusive but don't know how to avoid an endless loop.

```
private UpdateDefinition<T> setupSetValues<T>(T obj)
    {
        var updateBuilder = Builders<T>.Update;
        var updatedValues = new List<UpdateDefinition<T>>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (p.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
            {
                updatedValues.Add(updateBuilder.Set(p.Name, p.GetValue(obj)));
            }
        }

        return updateBuilder.Combine(updatedValues);
    }
```

What I have in my Db: 
{ "id": "1",
  "Name": "default_name",
  "Owner": {
      "Name": "owner_name",
      "Address": "owner_address"
        },
  "Car":{
       "Model": "car_model",
       "Color": "car_color"
   }
}

What I'm sending to the API:
{"id": "1",
  "Owner": {
    "Address": "new_owner_address"
   },
   "Car": {
        "Color": "new_car_color"
   }
}

What I expect:
{ "id": "1",
  "Name": "default_name",
  "Owner": {
      "Name": "owner_name",
      "Address": "new_owner_address"
        },
  "Car":{
       "Model": "car_model",
       "Color": "new_car_color"
   }
}

What I got:
{ "id": "1",
  "Name": "default_name",
  "Owner": {
      "Name": "null",
      "Address": "new_owner_address"
        },
  "Car":{
       "Model": "null",
       "Color": "new_car_color"
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just realized this is not the right approach to use MongoDb. I'm using arangoDb instead and now I can have a different collection for Owner and Car, and then use Join to relate each other. So when I need to update one of nested objects, I just have to call the right DAO.

Thanks!